# NgModel function inside *ngFor being run too times on start up

Tags: html, angular, typescript, loops, angular-material

I have a list objects called tutorials being displayed on screen. Each tutorial has a list of states inside it with a check box next to it as shown here:

My tutorials are coming from the database and the list of states is also coming from the database. Tutorials has a name and string array with a list of states associated with it.  This is my Html:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let t of tutorials" id="quote" class="quote">
    <div class="tutorial-name">
      {{ t.name }}
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let s of states" class="tutorial-states" id="">
      <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="checkIfTrue(t.states, s)" (click)="changeState(t.name,s)">{{ s }}</mat-checkbox>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The necessary check boxes are enabled as desired but the [ngModel]="checkIfTrue(t.states, s)" is running more times than desired. I have 3 tutorials and 3 different states so ngModel should only be triggered 9 times. I am putting a count on that function in my typescript:

```
  checkIfTrue(states: string[], state: string) {
    this.count += 1;
    console.log(this.count)
    if(states.includes(state)){
  return true;
}
```

Count is making it 252 or 54, which is way more than the desired 9.
Does anyone know as to why it is being triggered so much and how do I stop it?
Or is there an error in my loops and it is my fault for triggering it so much.

Comment: That's because angular runs that function during each change detection cycle to see if the value changed. That's also the reason you never want to bind a function to an input or interpolation. Use a variable and bind your ngModel to that and update the variable when needed. Additionally, you have a side effect in that function, which is not allowed in angular. If you were to bind that count variable to your template, you would see an error along the lines 'expression changed after it was checked'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why does the count increase?

You see this because you are binding a function to an input. Angular needs to recheck this input during each change detection cycle to determine if it needs to rerender. To do this, it needs to call your function during each cycle and compare the result to the previous result. I added an example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rvhe2j?file=src/app/app.component.html) where you can see this behaviour clearly (click on the button to trigger angular change detection).

#### How can you prevent that in your code?

Binding functions to your template is a bad practice in angular. The reason is exactly the problem you are seeing now: the function is called a lot. Hence, you can prevent this by not binding your function, but instead using a variable to bind to your template and update that variable whenever your state changes.

Comment: That example really cleared things.Thanks for the help